# HTTPS for EKS LoadBalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have LoadBalancer setup for a Deployment on EKS. I can access the app behind the classic load balancer AWS setup with the DNS name `<elb id>.<aws region>.elb.amazonaws.com`. I would like to add an HTTPS listener to this load balancer. The [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/terminate-https-traffic-eks-acm/) I have found says to create a certificate for the *custom domain* I am using. I don't want to use a custom domain now since the one I'm planning to use is currently being used in production. Is it possible to listen for HTTPS traffic using the `elb.amazonaws.com` DNS name given? AWS Certificate Manager will not let me request a certificate for the amazonaws.com domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get a certificate for elb.amazon.com. You have to use the certificate for the domain you own. You can get a cert from letsencrypt. Another option is to export your production certificate and key and use that on the load balancer (To avoid the browser warning you'll have to hardcode the elb IP to the prod domain name from the machine you'll test.).

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I want to test the app as an EKS pod in my staging environment first before using it in production. I think a work around would be to use a A record for a new subdomain of my custom domain.